# How to implement template control for dynamically add controls in wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, controltemplate

I have page with some control like picture. i want to add these control dynamically and when user click add those control add dynamically. how can i implement this? i want to use template control or something like this.

[image]

Comment: is that screenshot represent one control that you want to create template for?

Comment: i didn't got exactly what are you saying, Just explain in detail what content are static and which content dynamically you want add through this

Comment: I want when user click plus button these control add dynamically. sample label, persian translate label, textboxes and add voice button add dynamically in my form.

Comment: `DataTemplate` is what you are looking for.

Comment: How can i use datatemplate and how to bind from database?

Comment: Extract out a class say Model class which will contain properties needed to bind to View. Create ItemsControl and bind its ItemsSource to collection of that class instances. So, say you have one group of controls, it will have one item in collection and on click of button, add another item in a collection. Now to represent item on GUI, you can define `DataTemplate` which will contain two lables, two TextBoxes and one button. This way you need to define DataTemplate only once and based on data added in your collection, controls will be created on GUI. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to me using `Implicit Data Templates` is much easier then anything else `User Control` also a Good Choice but `Data Templates` OR `Implicit Data Templates` are much better.

Take a Look [Data Templates](http://wpftutorial.net/DataTemplates.html)

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you take "sample label, persian translate label, textboxes and add voice button" and put them in a usercontrol (Let's give it the name ***MyUserControl***)

then instead of adding that user control directly on the grid of your window, add a stack panel (lets name it ***MyStackPanel***), and add that user control into the stack panel (stack panel must have the orientation set to vertical)

---

Now when the user clicks on the "Plus" button your code will be:

```
MyStackPanel.Children.Add(new MyUserControl() { Margin = new Thickness(0, 5, 0, 0) });
```

This will give you the same controls you asked for with a margin top = 5.

---

You will only write code once for the user control, and all the added controls (after clicking on the plus button) will have the same code.

**Edit:**
If you want to delete MyUserControl when clicking the delete button add the following code for for the StackPanel (MyStackPanel) on the main window (look for ButtonBase.Click):

```
<StackPanel Height="236" HorizontalAlignment="Left" ButtonBase.Click="stackPanel1_Click" Name="stackPanel1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="491">
```

and for the event of the StackPanel:

```
 private void stackPanel1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (((UserControl1)e.Source).Tag.ToString() == "1")
        {
            stackPanel1.Children.Remove(((UserControl1)e.Source));
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Another button was clicked");
        }

    }
```

Now the delete button on the user control must have the following line of code:

```
 this.Tag = 1;
```